# What are "M14/125" pedals?

Tags: pedals, compatibility, vintage

While looking for [replacement pedals for my old French bike](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/pedals.html#tthreading), I've come across [products which are labelled as having thread size "M14/125"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P9HS3D0). Does this denote the "traditional French" threading of 14*1.25mm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this does.

Another option is to re-thread the cranks if you take it to the right bike shop, and then install a standard pedal.

Comment: Easier said then done. Don't forget that one side is threaded right hand threads. The other side is left hand threads. And left hand thread dies aren't cheap.

Comment: Which is why you take it to a bike shop, where they will have purchased them, rather than buy it yourself. After they ask you why you aren't just replacing the crankset, they'll probably do it.

Comment: Most modern bikes are threaded 9/16" x 20 threads per inch (which requires a .5118" to .5156" OD drill)  the 14x1.25 requires a .5039" drill so yeah you've got a shot. The only issue is the 14mm thread OD is larger than the .5156" dimension, so it's quite possible to do the re-tap and still not have enough metal in the right place to give you strength.   But I'm happy to admit when I'm wrong. I just checked the price on the taps.  I was way off base.  LH thread tap < $20 on Ebay.  RH tap should be around $10.  So a bike shop or buy the taps yourself and go to a machine shop locally.

Comment: The OD issue can be solved with drilling to oversize and installing a helicoil. This also keeps the different thread densities from interfering.

Comment: @OJS, right you are, but I have no clue where you'd go to find those inserts and the taps required for them.  9/16 x 20 threads per inch is not a very common size. Right hand thread is doable, left hand thread, not so easily.  It might be easier to attempt the simple drilled conversion from M14x1.25 to 9/16-20, see if that works. If not, Tig weld up the hole, bring it to a machine shop and cut 9/16-20 again.

Comment: @zipzit Typing "pedal thread hel" to Google search box autocompletes to helicoil and the first two results are instructions on how to install them and Amazon store that sells both inserts and taps.